# Default email queue не работает после использования php artisan queue:work

Tags: php, laravel

Хочу использовать default queue для  почты, для этого как сказано в  [ларавел документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#queueing-mail)

использую такую конструкцию

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class OrderShipped extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    //
}
```

после того как запускаю laravel queue `php artisan queue:work`
в консоли нечего не происходит, зависает так без ошибки только моргает курсор.

Правильная ли это реакция на артизан команду ?

Добавлю что почта до и после `php artisan queue:work`  посылается очень медленно.

Отсюда могу предположить что queue  не работает , потому что как я понял из документации queue сделана для  ускорения работы приложений.

Answer (score 1):

Очередь реализована для того, чтобы пользователь не ждал ответа сервера при выполнении длительных операций, например, именно почта. Таким образом, при отправке письма при каком-нибудь действии (например,подтверждении формы регистрации), пользователь сразу увидит следующую страницу, а почта будет отправляться в порядке очереди, если нет других задач.

Чтобы работала очередь, важно настроить драйвер очереди. Это может быть Redis, который использует библиотеку Predis, или реализовать очередь можно с помощью базы данных. Если задач планируется немного, то БД - хорошее решение.

Достаточно указать в **.env** файле 
`QUEUE_DRIVER=database`, а также создать необходимые таблицы. Это можно сделать следующим образом:

```
php artisan queue:table
php artisan migrate
```

И, разумеется, запустить слушатель:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

И всё будет работать.